# React using reactstrap navbar: how to add and remove class on navbar tag when window scrolls

Tags: javascript, reactjs, reactstrap

i have a react app, that has a reactstrap navigation.

how can i add and remove a class to navbar when the window is scrolled down to a certain height?

so the default state is having a classes of "navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-light stick-nav"

and when the window is scrolled 40px height the classes will become "navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-light bg-light fixed-top"

then when it is scrolled back at the top its classes will go back to its default state.

thanks in advance.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './Header.css';
import {
  Collapse,
  Navbar,
  NavbarToggler,
  NavbarBrand,
  Nav,
  NavItem,
  NavLink} from 'reactstrap';

class Header extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.toggle = this.toggle.bind(this);
    this.state = {
      isOpen: false
    };
  }
  toggle() {
    this.setState({
      isOpen: !this.state.isOpen
    });
  }



  render() {
    return (

        <Navbar expand="md" className="stick-nav">
          <NavbarBrand href="/">BrandName</NavbarBrand>
          <NavbarToggler onClick={this.toggle} />
          <Collapse isOpen={this.state.isOpen} navbar>
            <Nav className="ml-auto" navbar>
              <NavItem>
                <NavLink href="/link1" className="text-uppercase">link1</NavLink>
              </NavItem>
              <NavItem>
                <NavLink href="/link2" className="text-uppercase">link2</NavLink>
              </NavItem>
              <NavItem>
                <NavLink href="/link3" className="text-uppercase">link3</NavLink>
              </NavItem>
            </Nav>
          </Collapse>
        </Navbar>

    );
  }
}


export default Header;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with `window.addEventListener`.

```
componentDidMount() {
    window.addEventListener('scroll', this.mainMenuScroll, false);
}

componentWillUnmount() {
    window.removeEventListener('scroll', this.mainMenuScroll, false);
}

mainMenuScroll() {
    if (window.scrollY >= 40) {
        if (this.state.scrollClass !== true) {
           this.setState({
               scrollClass: true,
           });
        }
    } else if (this.state.scrollClass !== false) {
        this.setState({
            scrollClass: false,
        });
    }
}
```

Also, make sure to add `scrollClass` in this.state and bind the `mainMenuScroll` in the constructor.

And in the Navbar Component's `className` apply the classes you want when `this.state.scrollClass` is equal to `true`.